# Nexus 7 + Windows 7 = "A device attached to the system is not functioning." when transferring files from Nexus to Windows

Tags: nexus-7, windows

I connected a Nexus 7 (rooted Android 4.4.2) to my laptop (Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate). I see Nexus 7 in Windows Explorer and can browse the files in the Nexus 7, but when I tried to move files from Nexus to Windows I get the following error from Windows Explorer:

[image]

Reconnecting the Nexus 7 didn't help. Restarting Windows 7 did solve the issue, but I'm curious to know what can caused this error.

Comment: Same here. Don't know why this would be downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already, try a different USB port and make sure your Nexus is unlocked. Afterwards get the newest Google USB drivers and manually replace the drivers through Device Manager.

Comment: Didn't work but accepted to avoid Roomba.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt No need: open questions will only be roombad if they don't have any answers. Accepting the answer doesn't make any difference to roomba.

Comment: @DanHulme Prevent Misha / community from removing answer

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Upvoting is enough to prevent that. If the answer doesn't work for you, accepting it just makes you less likely to get better answers.

Comment: @DanHulme Upvoted answer may be removed by the poster

Answer (score 1):

using another cable solved this problem for me.

Comment: IMO if it works than it is an answer. There is not more that can be written though the poster could have commented on the  usefulness of the accepted answer to them.

Comment: Same here. With a good quality cable I still found that it would fail after the first few files. Tried with the original manuf cable (LG) and it worked much better.